# Will Gensim Word2Vec suffice min_count in case of online training of documents (that is training over big dataset partitioned in more than 50 files)

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to train Word2Vec Python via Gensim library. Data is of approximately 50GB and I have broken it down into 50+ files. I am training via below code.

For first file, it initializes and creates model. Then, for subsequent files it builds new vocab and retrain the same model over that.

```
if file_number == 0:
        model_domains = Word2Vec(domain_sentences, sg=1, hs=0, negative=5, vector_size=300, window=10, workers=16, min_count=50)
else:
        model_domains.build_vocab(domain_sentences, update=True)
        model_domains.train(domain_sentences, total_examples=len(domain_sentences), epochs=model_domains.epochs)
```

My query is that if we have provided **min_count = 50** which means that any word which is not greater than 50 won't be included in training of embeddings.
Now, because our data is distributed into 50+ files, hence, after training one file it can happen that word which had count of 30 in first file might get count 25 in second file. Will gensim than, include those words in creating embeddings or there will be information loss? Also, will it consider past file data to train for those words which had count less than 50?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you shouldn't be calling `.build_vocab()` & `.train()` multiple times on a Gensim `Word2Vec` model.

The usual & well-grounded way to train a `Word2Vec` model includes *all* available text, every epoch.

If you're instead doing 1/50th of the texts for N epochs, then another 1/50th for N epochs, etc, then you're doing something that's no longer quite the standard approach, and the learning-rate `alpha` won't be following the typical single-linear-decay, and parameterizations like `min_count` won't function quite right because the model will never have a true word-frequency count over the entire corpus.

Instead of applying code that invokes the model multiple times, it's better to use code that provides a single, re-iterable sequence view of the entire corpus. Then, as far as the model knows, it just iterates over that sequence as many times as it needs to - for one initial vocabulary survey, then N epochs – without knowing or caring where it's coming from. (It could be one file or 50 – the iteration works the same for the model.)

An article from the originator of Gensim covers this pattern:

https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/

A helper class in Gensim, `PathLineSentences', can already take a filesystem path to a directory, then treat all the files in that directory as if they were one giant (one-text-per-line, words-separated-by-spaces) single corpus. Its docs are at:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.PathLineSentences

But you could also use its code as a guide to write your own re-iterable sequence class that simply allows multiple iterations, each step yielding one list-of-words from whatever sources are appropriate. The most important quality of such a class is that it be not just a single-use *iterator*, but an *iterable* object that can give a *new* iterator every time another iteration is needed.

(If you mess this up, the `Word2Vec` vocabulary-survey step will work – the 1st iteration – but then all training will finish immediately, & ineffectively, warning about zero examples, leaving all words as random vectors.)